# Получить следующую запись по ID

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица с полями `id` и `title`. Известен `id` записи. Как получить следующую запись по `id`? Допустим, если `id` равно `4`, то получить запись с `id` `5` (или `66`, или `88`, в зависимости от номера следующей записи).

Comment: Может вам нужно `order by id`? А если выборкой, то что вам мешает `where id = @id+1`?

Comment: потому что id могут быть 4, 5, 6 а может и 4, 66, 88

Comment: Эмм... `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > 4 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 1`?

Comment: @Regent можете оформить как ответ? Вроде по смыслу подходит.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov полной уверенности в том, что именно это и  нужно, нет. Автор так и не ответил "да/нет".  Но почему бы и нет.

Comment: зачем вам получать следующую запись по id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получение следующей записи при заданном `id` текущей записи:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > 4 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 1
```